# Trying to display image retrived from server with base64 encoding but cant display the correct image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64

These are my encoding and decoding methods.

```
public String encodeBase64(Bitmap bit){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); // Could be Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG or Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP
    byte[] bai = baos.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(bai, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
public Bitmap decodeBase64(String base64Image){
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inMutable = true;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
    return bm;
}
```

This is encoded data from a bitmap

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAAdcCAYAAAC7T3KrAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU
eJzswQEBAAAAgJD+r+4ICgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.... etc
```

But the data i get from the server looks like this

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[105,86,66,79,82,119,48,75,71,103,111,65,65,65,... etc
```

I can get pure data or the type and data json object. Ive tried to decode both. When i try to decode with the type and data it gives me a null bitmap, when i decode the raw data only the image is not displayed, but nothing seems to crash.

Do i need to retrive all those array numbers and convert them to chars before decoding? Ive read other post and it sounded very straigtforward, just encode and then decode.

Comment: please provide a full example of your data, I would like to try your code by myself

Comment: You might need to convert `data:[...]` array to characters then use it

Comment: I cant print the full data array since its far to long and only a part of it shows up. i think its up to 32k bytes. I will convert the array into a string of chars then and then decode

Comment: Solved, you needed to convert the byte array into a string of chars and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
decode base_64 string Imgae in codigneter
$

aadharcard_front = image name(database)

 if(!empty($aadharcard_front))
    {
        $aadharcard_front = base64_decode($aadharcard_front);
        $aadharcard_front_time = time().'.png';
        file_put_contents(APPPATH.'../media/uploads/'.$aadharcard_front_time,$aadharcard_front);
        $user_data['aadharcard_front'] = $aadharcard_front_time;
    }
```